# A good way to validate incoming messages in Socket.IO?

Tags: node.js, validation, socket.io

When it comes to Express apps, to validate the contents of the body (order headers, or query), you can always create a validation middleware that would sit before the actual controller and in cases of invalid data, respond with an error.

Socket.IO does not support multiple callback chaining like Express does, so you can't use the same approach.

Is there a good way to validate the incoming message in socket.IO apart from doing a list of `if`'s to check every field in the handler?

Answer (score 4):

You can actually use `socket.use()` now in the latest version of socket.io, just like a middle ware in nodejs

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.use((packet, next) => {
    if (packet.doge === true) return next();
    next(new Error('validation error'));
  });
});
```

Comment: Mhm.. is it possible to somehow separate it by event name? If i'll have 40+ events, it means I'll need around the same amount of validation functions.

Comment: @VladislavAchramovic ,i think its not possible right now, but you can tweak a little bit by passing some parameter in the packet which you send to identify the event, also you can separate the code in to other file named as validation.js and import it, for better maintainability , pls up vote if you liked my answer

Answer (score 2):

This is a function that gets executed for every incoming Socket, and receives as parameters the socket and a function to optionally defer execution to the next registered middleware.

```
io.use((socket, next) => {
if (socket.request.headers.cookie) return next();
next(new Error('Authentication error'));
});
```

I hope This will solve Your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SocketioJWT:

```
var io            = require("socket.io")(server);
    var socketioJwt   = require("socketio-jwt");

    //// With socket.io < 1.0 ////
    io.set('authorization', socketioJwt.authorize({
      secret: 'your secret or public key',
      handshake: true
    }));
    //////////////////////////////

    //// With socket.io >= 1.0 ////
    io.use(socketioJwt.authorize({
      secret: 'your secret or public key',
      handshake: true
    }));
    ///////////////////////////////

    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
      // in socket.io < 1.0
      console.log('hello!', socket.handshake.decoded_token.name);

      // in socket.io 1.0
      console.log('hello! ', socket.decoded_token.name);
    })
```

For more validation options see [auth0/jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken).

Comment: not hat type of validation, JWT is used for authorization, while I need to validate the actual message, example: if the inbound object contains certain fields and they are in the specific format.